# Open an Embedded Object in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In an ms office document I've embedded / inserted an external document (object) (PDF in my case).

After opening the document, when I click on the PDF object icon, It opens up the PDF file embedded in it.

Using VBA / Macro I want to do the same thing, Where I'll have to run a macro and it will open up the embedded PDF file(Without clicking on the PDF ICON).

Is it possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 9):

**Excel:**

You can get the `OLEObject` form the `OLEObjects` of the `Worksheet`. See `OLEObjects` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840244.aspx, `OLEObject` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838421.aspx, `OLEObject` members - https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff841208.aspx.

There is a method `Verb` which has a verb for opening the object. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff838827.aspx - `Verb`s - https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff820926.aspx

Example:

```
Sub test()
 With ActiveSheet
  Set o = .OLEObjects("Objekt 1")
  o.Verb xlVerbOpen
 End With
End Sub
```

"Objekt 1" is the name of the object in the Excel worksheet. The object must be in the active sheet.

**Word:**

In Word it depends on if the embedded object is in an `InlineShape` or an `Shape`. And there is no `OLEObjects` collection. So you must handle with `Shape.OLEFormat`. See `InlineShapes` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822592.aspx, `Shapes` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845240.aspx, `Shape` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196943.aspx, `OLEFormat` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff197153.aspx.

Example:

```
Sub test()

 With ActiveDocument
  Set oShape = .InlineShapes(1) 'The embedded object is the first InlineShape.
  'Set oShape = .Shapes(1) 'The embedded object is the first Shape.
  Set oOLEFormat = oShape.OLEFormat
  oOLEFormat.Open
 End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! What about MS Word document. Can I do similar stuff with MS Word document Macro as well ?

Comment: In Word it depends on if the embedded object is in an `InlineShape` or an `Shape`. And there is no `OLEObjects` collection. So you must handle with `Shape.OLEFormat`. But there is no `MS-Word` tag in your Question and nowhere Word is mentioned. So why you are asking for Word now?

Comment: Sorry about that, But I got what I wanted to know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just wanted to add that if you are working with embedded Office files, it is possible to access them with `OLEObject.Object` property once you've opened them. I'm pretty sure you can do this with all other document types, like PDFs, but that would require separate libraries to be installed.

Answer (score 4):

In short, when you already know which object you are referring to:

**Excel**

```
Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("Object 1").Activate
```

**Word**

```
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).OLEFormat.Open
```

Comment: What should be the object for MS Word. In excel I got the object name by recording the operation. but office doesn't allow me to record the object clicking operation.?

Comment: There is a collection of InlineShapes and you can refer specified objet via it's number. From what I understand this numeration goes top-down and left-right. You can iterate through the objects you have in the file with below code - type of the object you want is 1: `cnt = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
For i = 1 To cnt
MsgBox ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i).Type
Next`

Comment: From what I see there is no .Name property as we get it in Excel with OLEObjects collection.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
    With ActiveSheet
        Set o = .OLEObjects("Objekt 1")
        o.Verb xlPrimary
    End With
End Sub
```