# Create dynamic link to embedded documents in Excel WITHOUT VBA

Tags: excel, hyperlink

Firstly, I realise this problem could be solved with VBA, but I am looking to keep this workbook macro-free.

What I am trying to do is have several Excel workbooks embedded into my workbook (each embedded workbook is specific to a factory). I want to create a cell that acts as a dynamic hyperlink, which changes depending on which factory is filtered (I don't have any issues creating this dynamic hyperlink myself). The part I don't know how to do, is create a hyperlink that opens a document that is embedded within the workbook. I can make a hyperlink that opens a file saved in a directory, but I need to be able to share this workbook with multiple users, therefore I am embedding the documents.

Hopefully this makes sense - to summarise; I need to create a button/hyperlink that opens an embedded document WITHOUT VBA.

Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

You have an EXCEL function **HYPERLINK** that receives a string (i.e. URL) as the first parameter. You can of course set ***BUILD*** the URL with a formula or a reference to other cell.

For instance, if you set in a cell the value:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com")
```

and link on it, Google's page will be open on your browser. If you set the link to point to a file (any file) it will open it with the suitable application (e.g. Excel).

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It's not really what I'm looking for. Unless you can tell me how to set a link to point to an embedded file?

Comment: Well, I don't quite see how you can create (even manually) an hyperlink to an **object** in Excel (where **object** would be your embedded file; note also that, from my experience, you normally cannot do via VBA things that you cannot do manually - this would be one of those cases). You can create hyperlinks to pages or even a specific cell within a sheet, but I don't think you can cause Excel to open an embedded file. Sorry.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479378/open-an-embedded-object-in-excel-using-vba

Comment: OK, but you cannot invoke it from a sheet, can you?