# Excel - opening file without selecting sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Say the current Excel workbook active sheet is named "MainSheet" and I want to insert a button at this sheet that will open a file that is at another sheet called "AuxiliarySheet".

This code works fine:

```
Sheets("AuxiliarySheet").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Name of my file")).Select
Selection.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary
```

But I want to open the file without having to go to the "AuxiliarySheer", so I tried to do this:

```
Sheets("AuxiliarySheet").Shapes.Range(Array("Name of my file")).Verb Verb:=xlPrimary
```

What gives me this error:

```
Run-time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

So the question is, can I open the file without using code Sheets("AuxiliarySheet")**.Select**?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479378/open-an-embedded-object-in-excel-using-vba

Comment: perfect, thank you.