# Documents.Open for embedded Word object

Tags: excel, vba, embedded-object

So I had this code in Excel VBA:

```
Dim oWord As New Word.Application
Dim objDoc
Set objDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("C:\folder\document.docx")
```

But now instead of having document.docx as an external Word document I embedded it on a sheet as an object (Object 1).
Therefore, I want to edit the code above to access the object instead of the external file.

In other words I want the code to be something like this:

```
'Set objDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(Object 1)
```

I have seen the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479378/open-an-embedded-object-in-excel-using-vba), but I want the line of code above and it doesn't explain how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: The question you linked to *does* explain how to do it though.. it's a quite different approach if the document is embedded.

Comment: If it does explain it then I probably don't understand, can you post how the new line of code is supposed to be?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54419143/edit-word-document-embedded-in-a-workbook-and-save-as-copy) may be a better question to reference actually. I think it's doing something similar to what you want.

Comment: Thank you. I will look at it. It seems to have a different approach but as you said, it has the same purpose I want.

Answer (score 0):

What I did eventually was use `.SaveAs` to "export" the embedded document in a certain location, then run my code using the exported document and delete it in the end.
This works for the purpose of my code.